# Cannot display graph using Networkx which contains node's name in Thai

Tags: python, matplotlib, nlp, networkx

I've been trying to plot a graph using networkx of which the nodes' name are Thai language. The problem is it cannot show in Thai and draw_networkx() does not provide parameter for utf_8. 
Please give me a suggestion.

```
import networkx as nx

G=nx.Graph()

G.add_node('กิน')
G.add_node('หิว')
G.add_node('ข้าว')
G.add_node('ถั่ว')
G.add_node('milk')

G.add_edge('กิน','หิว')
G.add_edge('กิน','ข้าว')
G.add_edge('กิน','ถั่ว')
G.add_edge('กิน','milk')

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos,node_size= 2400)
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way consists in changing the `font family` and passing it as a keyword argument when calling [nx.draw_networkx()](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html).

For example in my OS I have installed by default `Ayuthaya`.

```
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos,node_size= 2400,font_family='Ayuthaya')
```

This leads to the following output:

[image]